# Как в Laravel 8 вывести переменную из файла .env во вьюшку?

Tags: laravel

Вечер добрый, меня интересует как можно вывести, к примеру переменную APP_NAME из файла .env во вьюшку, что-то типа названия приложения в шаблоне.

Можно вариант с передачей через переменную с контроллера, я попробовал пару вариантов что-то не получилось ничего путнего...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Не стоит обращаться к `env` переменным в любом месте, кроме конфига.**

Причина - система кеширования конфигурации. Как только вводите команду `php artisan optimize` - фрейворк кеширует для быстрой работы всю конфигурацию, маршруты и т.п.

Итак ответ на ворпос

Создается новый конфигурационный файл `config/my_config.php` (имя файла для примера):

```
<?php
return [
  'var' => env('MY_VARIABLE')
];
```

после этого в коде этот параметр будет доступен так: `config('my_config.var')`

или открывается любой файл конфигурации в папке `config`, в зависимости от ваших целей, и по аналогии выше добавляется нужный параметр.

Переменная окружения `APP_NAME` устанавливает конфигурационный параметр `config('app.name');`

Comment: Благодарю за полный, развернутый ответ! Очень помог, всё ясно и понятно стало, там даже на примере в конфиге `app.php` есть пример того что я хотел, а ваш ответ еще и дополнил что и для чего так сделано!